# I cannot send multiple PHP value as a parameter of HTML onfocusout event function arguments

Tags: javascript

I am actually try to do something, in HTML PHP where I want to send multiple PHP values to JavaScript function, but when I send constant, that it work, but want to send php value, then it not work.

The main code is as follows:

```
$slots = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($slot = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slots))
{
    echo "<td width='11%' align='center'>";
    echo "<table width='100%' border='0' class='styler3'  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
    $batches = Batch_Info($day_department,$current_semester);
    while($batch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($batches))
    {
        echo "<tr><td align='center'><input type='text' style='width:96%;font-size:09px;' class='styler3' value='"; print($batch["batch_no"]);  echo "' onfocusout=Routine_Classes(this.value,'";   **echo $batch["batch_no"];**    echo "')></td></tr>";   
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</td>";
}
```

The ** code part is the problem. Here I send "Any String" its work, but Php value, that not work.

Please help me. how I send from here multiple values to JavaScript function.

Comment: It should work unless `$batch["batch_no"]` contains a single quote.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? What happens instead? Can you share the **generated** markup and your debugging attempts?

Comment: BTW, most people just use string concatenation or variable substitution, rather than separate `echo` statements for each part of the HTML.